# Игра "Крестики-Нолики" - C WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

Прошу помочь, подошёл к описанию логики и ни как не могу найти функцию которая бы определяла какой растровый образ размещён на кнопке (крестик - IDB_BITMAP1 или нолик - IDB_BITMAP2).

Например:

```
LRESULT result1 = SendMessage(hRadio[tmp], BM_GETIMAGE, 0, 0);

                if (!result1 == BST_CHECKED)
```

с помощью SendMessage можно определить наличие картинки на кнопке.

Прошу подсказать функцию, которая определить какая именно из картинок на кнопке и вернёт значение в переменную LRESULT.

Моего понимания пока не достаточно.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы делаете неправильно. Отделите модель от представления!

Ваша модель доски должна просто знать, в каком месте есть крестик или нолик. Для этого можно хоть завести квадратный массив энумов или применить любой другой из миллиона способов. Соответственно, уровень представления должен просто пробежаться по клеткам и вывести в нужном месте нужную картинку. «Читать» картинку обратно не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Двигаетесь в верном направлении - [BM_GETIMAGE вернет вам в LRESULT хендл картинки, которая стоит на кнопке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775987%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно какую цель ты преследуешь, но осмелюсь предположить что тебе необходима функция GetDlgCtrlID.

Comment: Чтобы проверить на выигрышную комбинацию - например три кнопки подряд по горизонтали это крестики.

Comment: @Aleksandr Fursenko, ты задаёшь слишком много разнообразных вопросов. Функция GetDlgCtrlID поможет получить идентификатор элемента управления, а это то что ты хотел.